# php_value is not working in .htaccess files

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using the code in .htaccess files like this:

```
<Directory "/home/star/public_html/test">
AllowOverride All
Options None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory> 
php_value upload_max_filesize 32M
```

It is giving the Internal Server Error. Can any one help me to correct it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: some hosts wont let you override php.ini files try contacting them. The code seems legit thou

Answer (score 4):

If you are running PHP in "CGI mode" and not as an Apache module, then using `php_value` as such will throw that "Internal Server Error".  In such case, set `upload_max_filesize` in `php.ini`.

Comment: When using a free hosting service, we don't have access to `php.ini`.

Comment: @vee, Requiring permission to php.ini is too much.

Answer (score 0):

The [<Directory />](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory) directive can only be used server-wide or in a virtual host -- you can't use it in .htaccess. First try removing that.

In some server environments, `php_value` may not work but `php_flag` will.

Comment: `php_value` and `php_flag` - either both work or neither work (depending how PHP is installed). You should never have the situation when one works and the other does not. `php_flag` is for setting _boolean_ values; `php_value` is used for non-boolean values - that's the only difference.